# How to add text-mask in ngx-mydatepicker in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using ngx-mydatepicker for date field. I need to add text-mask in that code. When i tried to add i got an error as "More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute".

How to add text-mask now? I used angular2-text-mask npm for text-mask. It works fine for other input field. But not in ngx-mydatepicker date field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to figure out the same, but when I searched for the error, I see people saying, it was [not able](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16755) to overcome this error.
So when you don't find a solution to your problem, always go vanilla.

**Solution:**

Add a Mask Helper in your project

```
export function MaskedDate(event: any) {
  var v = event.target.value;
  if (v.match(/^\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    event.target.value = v + '/';
  } else if (v.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}$/) !== null) {
    event.target.value = v + '/';
}
}
```

at your component:

```
import { MaskedDate } from './helpers/mask.helper';
```

Declare the property in your component:

```
  dateMask = MaskedDate;
```

In your component html:

```
 <input style="float:none"  (keyup)="dateMask($event)" formControlName="birth_date"  placeholder="Select a date"  ngx-mydatepicker [options]="myOptions" #dp="ngx-mydatepicker"/>
```

**You can still use text-mask with other inputs, no problem.**